# How can I build my own get address transactions API?

Tags: api

I want to build an API to query an arbitrary bitcoin address for received transactions. The address is not necessarily associated with my wallet. Is this possible using the commands in `bitcoin-cli`?

I do not want to rely on a third party service like `blockchain.com` Though a public code library would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NBXplorer: https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/blob/master/docs/API.md#address-transactions

How to setup NBXplorer? https://youtu.be/a5ehSfzYkJo

Requirements: Bitcoin Core and .NET Core SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Net-Bitcoin-RPC](https://github.com/edmlbox/.Net-Bitcoin-RPC) c# library to connect to your node and get the address.

```
BitcoinClient bitcoinClient = new BitcoinClient("http://127.0.0.1:8333", "alice:pass");
Wallet wallet = new Wallet(bitcoinClient);

//Optional.
AddressType addressType = AddressType.bech32;

//Optional.
string label = "best address";

string getnewaddress = await wallet.GetNewAddress(label, addressType);

Console.WriteLine(getnewaddress);
```